# Crop image based on largest quadrilateral contour OpenCV

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I am in high school and I am working on a project to build an iOS app that lets users scan business cards, currently I am working on edge detection on the card. I believe I have it working correctly and it is drawing the outline of the card and some other shadows ect.

Here is a sample image I got back while scanning, I should probably convert to grayscale which I'll do as well.

How can I find the largest quadrilateral and crop my image to included only the card? All of my contours are stored in a `vector<vector<cv::Point> >` The green line seems to be the one I'd be interested in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To find the largest quadrilateral you could just iterate over all and check for their dimensions/area.

The projection can be done with find `findHomography` and `warpPerspective`. You will need the four corner points of your quadrilateral and the four corresponding points in your reprojection (i.e. the corners of the image).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but in python, to find the largest contour, you would do something like:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours.sort(key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
```

cv2.contourArea is a lambda that calculates the area of a contour
reverse=True: descending order (biggest first)

Then the 0th element of contours is the biggest contour. Draw with:

```
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, 0, (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't aware of this method, will be very helpful for my problem.