# How to find the best quadrilateral to approximate an OpenCV contour?

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, augmented-reality, contour

I have an OpenCV contour `c` which is close to a quadrilateral in its shape, but it can have 4 to multiple of dozens of points.

I want to find the quadrilateral `q` which is the closest to the contour `c` (one way could be to minimize the area of the difference between them).

I currently use

```
q = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(c, True), closed=True)
```

but the result is **not always a quadrilateral**. I have already tried techniques like those in [cv2.approxPolyDP() , cv2.arcLength() How these works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274412/cv2-approxpolydp-cv2-arclength-how-these-works) and in [How to force approxPolyDP() to return only the best 4 corners? - Opencv 2.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028961/how-to-force-approxpolydp-to-return-only-the-best-4-corners-opencv-2-4-2) (binary search for example), but it doesn't always yield a quadrilateral.

**Is there another way (probably with something else than `approxPolyDP`?) to find the best quadrilateral approximation to a contour?**

Note: another linked question is [Crop image based on largest quadrilateral contour OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490858/crop-image-based-on-largest-quadrilateral-contour-opencv) but it does not give a solution to this problem.

Comment: I am afraid that this problem is arduous. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226436325_Minimum_area_circumscribing_Polygons
If your shape is close to a rectangle, the tightest rectangle is much easier to find.

Comment: Thanks for the link @YvesDaoust. This seems to be for the *circumscribing* polygon. I don't know if it changes the level of difficulty, but I'm okay about any quadrilateral, not specifically circumscribing. Do you think it can be doable with a minimization of the area in the symmetrical difference of `c` and `q`?

Comment: Certainly more difficult.

Comment: look at all the algorithms used by various AR markers and their detection methods. -- no, opencv has no simply usable function that preserves edges (and infers true corners). approxPolyDP is old stuff, and it "preserves" corners, while completely butchering (moving) edges. -- maybe someone should do a GSoC and implement some of these methods, or refactor the relevant parts from the aruco code. it has a few refinement methods (apriltag etc)

Comment: btw, it pays to shrug off that academic vagueness/abstraction that hobbles all the academics. you talk of "quadrilaterals". *show* what you're really talking about.

Comment: For me [cv.minAreaRect()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9) was good enough to solve the problem, although it may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Y_Z can you post an answer with sample code? It might be a good solution!

Comment: Please post your input image. We need to see an example!

Comment: See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303329343_Least-squares_Fitting_of_Polygons

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar problem, but instead of approximating a contour with a general quadrilateral, I tried to approximate it with a rectangle. I hope that my solution would be helpful to your problem as well. 
I used the [cv.minAreaRect](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9) method. This method finds the enclosing `Rotated Rectangle` of a set of points with minimal area.
In python opencv, a `Rotated Rectangle` is built out of `(center_x, center_y), (width, height), angle_in_degrees`. I suggest you to check [this link](https://theailearner.com/tag/angle-of-rotation-by-cv2-minarearect/) to avoid confusion about the returned `angle_in_degrees` value, and for more useful information regarding "minAreaRect" method.
Here is a simple usage example of the "minAreaRect" method:

```py
import cv2

def check_rectangle_approx(contour):
    rectangle = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
    (center_x, center_y), (width, height), angle = rectangle

    return width * height - cv2.contourArea(contour) < SOME_THERSHOLD_VLAUE
```

In my case, where I had close to rectangle contours, `minAreaRect()` returned decent approximations. Hope it will be the same for you.